# return match words from a search query

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I'd like to find match words between two tables. 
this query works well, but **I want to get the exact matched words as well as id.**

```
SELECT id
FROM debug_fullText
where title ~~* any (select matchWords from debug_matchWords)
```

here  is debug_fullText:

```
id        |title        |tags                                    |description
3893382135|"Tate Modern"|"london;londra;nut;squirrel;Westminster"|"Later that day I got to thinking about relationships.
```

and the matchwords is:

```
id|words
1 |"Westminister"
2 |"Tate Modern"
3 |"South Afrika"
4 |"London"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other methods, but here is one:

```
SELECT ft.id, mw.words
FROM debug_fullText ft, lateral
     (select array_agg(matchword) as words, count(*) as cnt
      from debug_matchwords
      where title ilike matchWord
     ) mw
where mw.cnt > 0;
```

Here is an example:

```
with debug_fulltext as (
      select 1 as id, 'a b c'::text as title
     ),
     debug_matchwords(matchword) as (
      values ('%a%'::text), ('%b%')
     )
select ft.id, mw.words
from debug_fullText ft, lateral
     (select array_agg(matchword) as words, count(*) as cnt
      from debug_matchwords
      where title ilike matchWord
     ) mw
where mw.cnt > 0;
```

This returns both words.

EDIT II:

This returns the match for me:

```
with debug_fulltext as (
      select 3893382135 as id, 'Tate Modern'::text as title
     ),
     debug_matchwords(id, matchword) as (
      values (1, 'Westminister'),
             (2 , 'Tate Modern'),
             (3 , 'South Afrika'),
             (4 , 'London')
     )
SELECT ft.id, mw.words
FROM debug_fullText ft, lateral
     (select array_agg(matchword) as words, count(*) as cnt
      from debug_matchwords
      where title ilike matchWord
     ) mw
where mw.cnt > 0;
```

If it doesn't work for you, then there might be character set issue or a bad character masquerading, say, as a space.

Comment: Thanks it worked. :)
when you said other methods,
do you mean there might be other methods which are more faster or not necessary!

Comment: but it does not return back all the match words! it stopped when found the first match!

Comment: @Raha1986 . . . That is probably the way you are printing out the array.  Perhaps you should use `string_agg()` instead of `array_agg()`.

Comment: thanks for taking time,
your example works properly, but mine still the same!
I added tables to show you how they look like

Comment: yes, you are right,
I caste it and it worked :)      `SELECT ft.id, mw.words
FROM debug_regexfreeFlickrFullInfo ft, lateral
     (select array_agg(plainto_tsquery(field_3)) as words, count(*) as cnt
      from debug_gb
      where title ilike field_3 or tags ilike field_3 or descriptio ilike field_3
     ) mw
where mw.cnt > 0;`